# VB.net - Import certificate, bind with private key and install on USB PKI token

Tags: vb.net, ssl, smartcard, pki

So what I'm trying to do is import an existing certificate (DER, CER and/or PEM formatted), onto a USB PKI token which already has the private key that matches the certificate.

First of all, I'm able to successfully add the certificate to the windows certificate store (My/Personal) using code in VB.net.
Second, I am even able to match and bind the certificate to the key (using certutil -repairstore for this, executed from within my vb.net program)

Now the problem: The above part adds the certificate to the PC store, and matches it with the key for usage on that machine. However, the certificate is not actually added to the USB PKI token. Meaning if I move it to a different PC, I've only got the private key there.

Now, I do believe it should be possible to have it added to the token (which has its own CSP btw.)

Reason why, is that if I insert the token to a PC, and import the certificate itself directly into the Certificate Manager through the MMC in windows, it will automatically match with the private key AND also install it on the token itself.

It feels like this should be possible then by coding as well, no?
I've also tried it through the powershell, but no luck. certutil is able to import certificates directly on the token, however, only if you supply a PFX file, which I don't have, seeing how the private key is only available on the token.

Currently, importing is done by:
Dim collection = New X509Certificate2Collection()

```
    collection.Import(V_EndEntity)

    Dim store = New X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)

    store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed)

    Try
        For Each certificate As X509Certificate2 In collection
            store.Add(certificate)
        Next
    Finally
        store.Close()
    End Try
```

Any suggestions?